# Problem occurs while trying to set Firebase storage image into ImageView Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-imageview, android-glide

I am trying to retrieve an image from firebase storage, and load into an ImageView named `circleImageView` using **Glide**. But it is not working as expected, instead of showing the image the `circleImageView` becomes invisible. Here is the code where I tried to load the image:

```
public void showUserDataOnActivity(){
        nameInput.setText(usuario.getNome());
        emailInput.setText(usuario.getEmail());
        phoneInput.setText(usuario.getPhoneNumber());
        if (usuario.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(usuario.getPhotoUrl());

            Glide.with(ProfileActivity.this).load(storage.child("user_avatar").child(usuario.getUid() + ".jpeg")).into(circleImageView);
        }
        else {
            circleImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_photo);
        }
    }
```

### This is my expected result:

[image: This is my expected result]

### This is the current result:

[image: This is the current result]

Comment: try to add `.getValue()` at the end of `load`.
from what i Know about firebase, `child()` is only a reference, not a real value.
You want a url in the `load` function, so you need the actual url of your firebase content.

Comment: That is how to reference documentation explains.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files?hl=pt-br

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the correct url of the image?

Comment: I'm not using url. Im using the storage reference. When debugging i see the file information from the firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that somehow the CircleImageView is becoming invisible, try setting visibility to visible again.

```
circleImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_photo);
circleImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```